# Solving the inequality $a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3≥k(a+b+c+d)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

The problem is:
Find all real numbers $k$, such that the inequality 
$a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3≥k×(a+b+c+d)$
holds for any $a, b, c, d \in [-1, +\infty)$

At first I thought of havimg 2 cases:
If all are negative and if all are positive, but I get no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a=b=c=d=1$ we get $k\leq 1$.

If $a=b=c=d=-1$ we get $k\geq 1$.

So $k=1$.

And as Pedro pointed out (read comment) we have no solution.

Comment: If $a=b=c=d=\frac{1}{2}$ we get $k\leq1/4$. If $a=b=c=d=-\frac{1}{2}$ we get $k\geq1/4$. So...?

Comment: No such $k$....

Answer (score 0):

If $a=b=c=d\rightarrow0^+$ we get $k\leq0$.

If $a=b=c=d\rightarrow0^-$ we get $k\geq0$.

Thus, $k=0$, for which our inequality is obviously wrong: $a=b=c=d=-1$.

Thus, we have no some needed value of $k$.